# Erlang and OTP in Action: why cannot call get_count in telnet?

Tags: erlang, distributed, erlang-otp, gen-server

In the book ["Erlang and OTP in Action"](http://www.manning.com/logan/), chapter 3, there is a [`tr_server` example](https://github.com/erlware/Erlang-and-OTP-in-Action-Source/blob/master/chapter_03/tr_server.erl). I have some questions about it:

1. Why can we not call `tr_server:get_count().` in telnet? The book states that the `handle_info/2` function would synchronously call `gen_server:call/2`. Can anyone provide more details about the problems with that?
2. And, what's the relationship between `tr_server`, `gen_server`, `erl console` and `telnet`?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the first question is in the book, page 117, where there's a separate frame entitled "A server should not call itself". The problem is that since the code runs in a `gen_server`, it is effectively inside its own message reception loop at the point where you'd try to invoke `tr_server:get_count()`. The implementation of that function works by sending a message to the `gen_server` and then blocking to wait for a reply, but the message loop is already blocked inside `handle_info/2` handling your request to call `tr_server:get_count()`. Any attempt by the `gen_server` process to call itself again at that point results in deadlock.

As for the second question:

- `tr_server` is the callback module for use with `gen_server`. The standard `gen_server` module implements a message reception loop, handling some of the messages itself, specifically system messages, and calling the `tr_server` module callbacks to handle all other messages, which are application messages.
- The Erlang shell implements a read-eval-print loop (REPL). It accepts input from the user in the form of Erlang function calls and its own shell commands, executes them, and presents the results to the user. The `tr_server` is similar to the shell, but the shell much more capable and comprehensive.
- [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) is an ancient yet still effective way of interactively accessing a remote internet host. Read the link for more details.

Comment: thx. Could you provide more details about "relationship between erlang shell and gen_server" ? In Unix shell, it executes a command could fork a new process, but in erlang shell, what happens if we execute a command?

Comment: Calling a function in the Erlang shell means that the function runs in the shell process. Should the function cause the process to die, then a new shell process takes its place. You can see this in the shell by first calling the function `self().` to get the pid of the current shell process, then running a function that will kill that process, say `exit(foo).`, and then calling `self().` again. You'll see that the second call to `self().` returns a different pid than the first one.

Comment: @songhir The most interesting things about functions running in the shell's process happen when you `spawn_link` from the shell -- then the shell's process is linked to whatever you spawned. When that thing crashes so does the shell's current process. But the shell is also supervised, so a crash doesn't *appear* to kill the shell, because it starts right back up. As you play around you'll eventually encounter something funky-seeming in the shell as a result of this. Just keep in mind that "the shell is a process, too".